# Warning: imagejpeg 'Failed to open stream' on product update Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product-images, permissions

When attempting to save a product (transferred originally from Mage 1 database) in Magento 2 I am receiving the following error.

*Warning: imagejpeg(/var/www/html/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/1/swatch_image/30x20/beff4985b56e3afdbeabfc89641a4582/s/m/small-table_4_2.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php on line 181*

If I visit this location **in the file system the image does not exist**.

If I look in the product page of **admin panel** or on the **front end** I can see **no call to this specific image link**.

Can anyone please assist?

Answer (score 1):

Try to clear Catalog product image cache.

Make sure that `/var/www/html/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/` is writable for the Magento user (maybe apache or nginx). Check parent folders also.

Try to delete `var/di` `var/generation` `var/cache` folders too.

Do you use swatch image for products ?

Comment: No we don't use swatch images for products. I will give that a try and let you know.

Comment: I get a permissions error when I try and run flush image cache. So I am guessing this will be the cause, and solution to my problem. I will update in due course.

Answer (score 0):

**This is resolved** by giving all directories in /pub/ folder **775** permissions for the magento user. or we can give **777** permissions

Comment: Be sure to meet the permission documentation for security issue : http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html `vendor` `app/etc` `pub/static` `var`